# how to open a url in chrome browser in android using uiautomation

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I want to open the url `www.youtube.com` in `Chrome browser` on my android device using `ui-automator`.

I am able to enter the `URL`, but it doesn't have an `UI button 'GO' or 'Enter'` to start loading the website.

Once done with `setText` of URL, any suggestions on how to simulate `'GO' or 'Enter' button press` on keypad to start loading the website?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont get what you really want. open Browsr by intent of your own App? Or just open a link from fav listß

Comment: @raja:I think you have to use setOnKeyListener for that.

Comment: @Born To Win I cant get you, Can you explain me with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once done with `setText`,

`UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance();
device.pressEnter();`

should do the job

Comment: Its working thank you anvesh. But one small change instead of getUiDevice().pressEnter() I used 
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance();
device.pressEnter(); Because it gave null pointer exception.